# How to reinstate toolbars on an embedded PDF with Firefox and Adobe Reader plugin?

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-reader, embedded

Using Firefox I was viewing a PDF file embedded within a web page, with the toolbar available. After right-clicking to deselect the toolbar (I was testing something) I cannot find a way to reinstate them. Since the toolbar is enabled by right clicking on the toolbar area, when it's disabled, it's not obvious how to reenable it.

When the toolbars have been disabled and no longer visible, how do you reinstate them?

---

Version info:

```
Firefox 3.6.3  
Adobe Reader 9.3  
Kubuntu 10.04
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general shortcut to reset the toolbars is **Alt-F8** (Windows) or **Ctrl-Shift-F8** (Unix), see [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Reader/8.0/help.html?content=WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7aec.html) (Adobe Reader 8) and [How to reset toolbars in Adobe Reader 9](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-reset-toolbars-adobe-reader-9-305645/).

Pressing **F8** brings back the Toolbar on Windows (Firefox 3.6.3, Adobe Reader 9.3.2).

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for answering, but that didn't work for me. Is that for a Linux OS?

Comment: No, this is on Windows 7, sorry, Linux might be different...

Comment: Found something else (see edit)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F8 works, cheers!